# RoundRectangle looks stretched

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to render a round rectangle on the screen but it looks as if it's been stretched.

```
private void init(){
            mOuterRect = new RectF(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
            //other stuff
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {


            canvas.scale(getWidth(), getHeight());

            drawRect(canvas);

        }

private void drawRect(Canvas canvas) {

        float radius = 0.05f;


        canvas.drawRoundRect(mOuterRect, radius,radius, mOuterRectPaint);



    }
```

I think it has something to do with the scaling and I tried to fix that but I got worse results. What exactly is causing the image to get stretched like this?

[image]

Comment: what happens if you dont scale it at all?

Comment: I see nothing on screen. I'm not sure if it gets rendered outside the bounds of the screen. I tried translating the canvas to see if I could move it inside the screen but it didn't help.

Comment: The problem comes from your the scaling of your Canvas. Seeing as it doesnt do anything if you dont scale it that means it probably has a width and height of 1. You need to setup your view correctly in your XML. Double check your XML Layout and ensure that this canvas is set to fill the parent.